# How to link user between Wordpress vs. Parse.com db's

Tags: wordpress, passwords, parse-platform

I am using a web site installed with Wordpress and a Mobile app that uses Parse.com to store its data.

Now I want the User Registration on either solution to automatically register a user on the other.
Example: When a new user register on the Wordpress based web site a PHP script should automatically create a User Object in Parse.com datastore - and here is the problem - WITH SAME PASSWORD!

I can easily create a user in Parse.com data store from the action hook register_user from Wordpress, but how do i transfer that same password to the new Parse.com user account, so that when the user next time log in through the Mobile app, they just use the same password as they used when registering their account in Wordpress?

The other way around, when registering as a new user in the Mobile App saving to Parse.com User Object, how can the same password be transferred to a Wordpress user account!

Comment: **Please** do not share passwords like this. Use oauth to allow the user to create a password in one place and delegate authority. Do not just assume they want you to register them on another site. And do not try to login to another site anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but the Mobile App is an app using the same data - it is not another site, it is an app supporting the website and vice versa. I will read up on oath...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that exchanging passwords from one database to another is not the solution, neither does OAuth solve my problem. only solution is to stick with only one database being called from both systems - at least for the account information.

Comment: I have the same problem to solve and am trying to figure out a reasonable solution. Certain features require at least synchrony between Parse and WordPress accounts for each user. Maybe an option to create the WP account when the mobile account is created? (With the same password -- most users are not going to use two different passwords.)